# search box doesn't line up in menu in Drupal 7 menu

Tags: drupal, navigation

I added the search box in my top menu in Drupal 7.  The search box is about 80px too low.  When you scroll down and the sticky menu comes up, the search box is lined up correctly.  Has anyone dealt with this before?

Thanks

William Hodge

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you provide some example code (html & css)? This is more CSS related than Drupal related..

Comment: Thanks for replying but I found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple.  I just had to float:right the search box.  I thought the module allowed the search to be a part of the menu.  It merely placed it in that section.  So, I had to change the size of the search box and float it right.  The issue comes back up if another item is added to the menu.